# Iterating over a list of skus in jQuery to dynamically add it to HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm at a beginner level in front-end development; I'm attempting to refactor some code as a side project for myself to improve my skills. My job has a list of images targeted by their skus being dynamically added to div's. I have included the following code that I have attempted to refactor.

```
var getProductNavigateDetail = function(skuList) {
  var postUrl = "/Browse/ProductDynamicComponent/GetProductNavigateDetailJson";
  $.ajax({
    url: postUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: { skus: skuList },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      if (result[0] != null) {

        $('#a1Price').html(result[0].FormattedPrice);
        $('#a1Name').html(result[0].Name);
        $('#a1Link').attr('href', result[0].NavigateUrl);
        $('#a1Link').attr('href', result[1].NavigateUrl);

        $('#b1Price').html(result[1].FormattedPrice);
        $('#b1Name').html(result[1].Name);

        $('#c1Price').html(result[2].FormattedPrice);
        $('#c1Name').html(result[2].Name);
        $('#c1Link').attr('href', result[2].NavigateUrl);

        $('#a2Price').html(result[14].FormattedPrice);
        $('#a2Name').html(result[14].Name);
        $('#a2Link').attr('href', result[14].NavigateUrl);
        $('#b2Price').html(result[15].FormattedPrice);
        $('#b2Name').html(result[15].Name);
        $('#b2Link').attr('href', result[15].NavigateUrl);
        $('#c2Price').html(result[16].FormattedPrice);
        $('#c2Name').html(result[16].Name);
        $('#c2Link').attr('href', result[16].NavigateUrl);
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}

getProductNavigateDetail('160555,665087,159816,482743,228984,519217,320165,216235,229010,687943,332256,513663,482508,216243,330495,340218,668637,232524,414899,444139,560632,329734');
```

It seems pretty obvious that it just needs to iterated over with a loop so I made this code.

```
var getProductNavigateDetail = function(skuList) {
  var postUrl = "/Browse/ProductDynamicComponent/GetProductNavigateDetailJson",
      imageURL = "www.website.com/";
  $.ajax({
    url: postUrl,
    type: "POST",
    data: { skus: skuList },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(result) {
      if (result[0] != null) {
        for (let i = 0; i < skuList.length; i++) {
          $('#a' + [i] + 'Price').html(result[i].FormattedPrice);
          $('#a' + [i] + 'Name').html(result[i].Name);
          $('#a' + [i] + 'Link').attr('href', result[i].NavigateUrl);
          $('#a' + [i] + 'Image').attr('src', imageURL + result[i].ImagePath);
        }
      }
    },
    error: function(jqXhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      console.log(textStatus, errorThrown);
    }
  });
}

getProductNavigateDetail('160555,665087,159816,482743,228984,519217');
```

Trying to figure out a way to get the implementation of the first but just using a short iteration with jQuery. Any tips, advice or scenarios to look at would be gladly appreciated!

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what the loop is.  Because you are setting `$('#a1Link')` twice in there.  And you jump from index 2 to index 14.  Is this the code verbatim?  Also `skuList` isn't an array.  It's a string with skus separated by comma.  You'd have to split it on comma to get an array

Comment: You're on the right track. 2 things to look at: I think you're expecting `skuList.length` to be 6, but it's not. And what does `'#a'+[i]+'Price'` evaluate to?

Comment: Yeah I was trying to figure out how to get the length of items in a function. I know how to get them from an array. And so far none of the code I refactored was really evaluating to anything Because I dont think its actually pulling correct data. What i was trying to do with the #a+[i]+price is basically target the class name in the HTML code based on the iteration.

Comment: Also sorry the code was verbatim but i removed the 12 other sections. it had that repeating code from 1 all the way to 14.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so `result` is the response from the AJAX request, and I'm assuming this is an array of products. such as:

```
[ { FormattedPrice: 'somethin', Name: 'someName' } ]
```

What you send as data is a comma-seperated list of SKUs (`'160555,665087,159816,482743,228984,519217'`). Firstly, you assume that the result you get back is in the exact same order as your comma-seperated list you sent in, and that it will always contain the same number of products as you have asked for. If any products are missing from the database, and your array is 1 less than you expect, you will get an error in your loop as your try and access that missing array entry...

Secondly, your loop is not going to implement the exact same thing as what is done in the original code (the div ID's can start with either `a`, `b` or `c`, and then it jumps from `results[2]` to `results[14]`). So I am unsure how you are going to target the correct div ID with only the index of the array you are looping through unless it follows a strict pattern.

So overall I'm not entirely sure what you need to achieve and it would be hard to write the code for you without seeing the full `result` object and your front-end HTML.

Comment: Exactly! So the whole missing SKU causing the code to break was going to be my next step at refactoring this, as that was a known bug. So I was hoping to find a way to loop through the length of items in the sku function or create an error handler in case what you mentioned happened. So basically the original code is all hardcoded to accept the individual skus. I basicaly want to just want to plug in the data from a sku to the HTML code. in that same div, a paragraph with a classname needs to be added as well as a paragraph id with the price. It seems simple in my head.

Comment: Ok so I'm assuming what you need is a to generate a new DIV for each result and add HTML to it. What you actually need to do is, instead of targeting hard-coded divs in the HTML template, is to have one container div (let's call it `#container`) and append the child divs to it as you go along (check http://api.jquery.com/append/).

You can create <a> elements and <img> elements using javascript/jquery.

Let me know if this is the approach you want to take and I can suggest some more code

Comment: That actually does sound like a good solution. Yeah if you could point me in there right direction I would gladly appreciate it! I guess the tricky part for me is iterating through the function call's list of skus.

Comment: To iterate through it, convert the comma seperated string to an array with `skuList.split(',')`. Then you can do your `for let i=0; i<skuList.length; i++` loop.

Comment: Demo of dynamically adding div's to a container with jQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/dkL6f5dz/13/